# In a moving average model, how do I calculate the errors?

Tags: arima, moving-average

I am programming an ARIMA model. The MA part of the model uses past forecast errors. How do I calculate these errors? Should I use any other model?

Comment: See [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/8) for a description (basically past $e$ values come from residuals, future ones are replaced by their expectation, 0).